# Ran into this at work "operator ClassName *". What does this mean?

Tags: c++

The class with this code is a reference class for a pointer of ClassName, i.e.:

```
class ClassName;

class ClassRef
{
    ClassName* m_class;
    ...
    operator ClassName *() const { return m_class; }
...
```

I am assuming this is used for pointer validity checks, such as:

```
ClassRef ref(new ClassName())
if (ref) { bla bla bla }
```

Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: Is it `classname` or `ClassName`? Please be *precise* in code presented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an overload of the conversion operator. Whenever a `ClassRef` object needs to be converted to a `ClassName` pointer type, this operator is called.

So;

```
ClassRef r;
ClassName * p = r;
```

will make use of this overload.

Comment: So I just wrote a little test involving two classes - Base and Ref. When I tried using the reference within an "if" statement this operator overload got called - why?

Comment: @NindzAI: the "if" requires whatever thing can be evaluated 0 or non-0. Classname cannot, but ClassRef* (being a pointer) can. And since `ref` can be converted into a pointer via that conversion operator, that's called.

Comment: @NindzAl That's because while the compiler attempts to obtain a value that can be used in place of a `bool` expression it finds that the `ClassRef` can be converted to a pointer type. You'll notice that if you provide a conversion operator to a `bool` directly, that one will be preferred. And if you provide a conversion to another pointer type, you'll get a compiler error due to the ambiguity.

Comment: @enobayram So, in essence I can override conversion to ANY pointer type. If I have N overrides with N > 1, and among the overrides I have a conversion operator to a bool. Am I correct in assuming the compiler would not complain about ambiguity and simply prefer the bool conversion when has to deal with "if", "while" etc?

Comment: @NindzAI yes, as long as one of the alternatives is conversion to `bool` directly, there's no ambiguity.